# How to redirect on checkout page, after add to cart click on bundle product?

Tags: addtocart, redirect, magento2.3.1, bundled-product, checkout-page

I need to integrate small stuff.

***When I will click add to cart ( bundle product )  then only product added successfully in cart page and then redirect into the checkout page.***

So please let me help. 
Please make sure only bundle product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use [observer/event](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html) at here.**

**Create Observer** event on `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`.

and set return `return_url` to request Url as checkout page url when you doing to add to cart.

### Observer class:

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Magento\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CheckoutCartAddProductComplete implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;

    public function __construct(
         \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url      
    ) {

        $this->url = $url;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $request= $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
        if($product->getTypeId() !== 'bundle'){
            return ;
        }
        /**
         * 
         */
        $checkoutUrl = $this->url->getUrl('checkout');
        $request->setParam('return_url',$checkoutUrl);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

**Note that:** This solution is work When Setting `when After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart` = `Yes`.